# Save _FillValue from netCDF file

Tags: netcdf4

I have a datasat that has a specific _FillValue defined, this is the ncdump output:

```
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: data.nc
Size is 2688, 2016
Origin = (89.988090807592116,30.011910669975187)
Pixel Size = (0.023818384815780,-0.023821339950372)
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"data.nc":data
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[2016x2688] toa_brightness_temperature (16-bit integer)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  89.9880908,  30.0119107) 
Lower Left  (  89.9880908, -18.0119107) 
Upper Right ( 154.0119092,  30.0119107) 
Lower Right ( 154.0119092, -18.0119107) 
Center      ( 122.0000000,   6.0000000) 
Band 1 Block=1344x1008 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-32768
  Unit Type: K
  Offset: 244.291473388672,   Scale:0.0018558754818514
  Metadata:
    add_offset=244.29147
    coordinates=time
    keywords=Infra-red, brightness temperature
    long_name=toa_brightness_temperature
    NETCDF_VARNAME=data
    scale_factor=0.0018558755
    standard_name=toa_brightness_temperature
    units=K
    _FillValue=-32768
```

I can see the _FillValue above, but is it possible to save this as a variable in Python?

Comment: That should be easy; can you share a small example NetCDF file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean as the above output is my example netCDF file ?

Comment: No, that's a dump of the header. It is easier to construct a working example/answer if we have the actual NetCDF file to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this should work in netcdf4-python:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

nc = Dataset('data.nc')
var = nc.variables['data']
fill_value = var._FillValue
```